# Finding rows that do not have particular child rows

Tags: sql

I have two tables that pertain to images:

```
ImageInfo
---------
Id
Name
Photographer

Images
------
Id
ImageInfo_Id
Quality
URL
```

`Images` has a many-to-one foreign key relationship with `ImageInfo`, and can hold various qualities-- 600, 800 and other pixel resolutions, for a given ImageInfo entry.

What I'm after are all ImageInfo IDs that do *not* have a 600 pixel quality entry in the Images table.  How can I best do this?  I'm thinking of a left outer join or maybe `where not exists` statement but wanted to solicit opinions before going that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like `not exists`

```
select ii.*
from imageinfo ii
where not exists (select 1
                  from images i
                  where i.ImageInfo_Id = ii.id and
                        i.quality = '600 pixel' -- or whatever
                 );
```

You can also phrase this as a `left join`, but `not exists` is almost a direct translation of your question.